# Como fazer curva ROC - AUC invertida no R?

Tags: r

Boa noite

Estou precisando de ajuda para fazer a curva ROC no R.

Estou utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
library(ROCR)

pred <- prediction(predictions = banco$ic, labels = banco$SM)

perf <- performance(pred, measure = "tpr", x.measure = "fpr")

plot(perf, main = "ic", col = "blue", lwd = 3)

abline(a = 0, b = 1, lwd = 2, lty = 2)

perf.auc <- performance(pred, measure = "auc")

unlist(perf.auc@y.values)
```

A variável "ic" é contínua, e significa índice de conicidade.
A variável SM é categórica (binária), e significa síndrome metabólica (0 - sem SM; 1 - com SM).

Fiz a curva com essas variáveis no SPSS e ela fica acima da linha diagonal com AUC = 0,7519.

Fiz também no R, com as mesmas variáveis, mas a curva fica abaixo da linha diagonal com AUC = 0,2481. Esse valor de AUC que deu no R é complementar ao que deu no SPSS.

No SPSS sei que é necessário identificar o estado da variável (foi colocado 1, pois 1 representa os doentes) e em opções é necessário identificar a direção (a opção marcada foi "um resultado do teste menor indica um teste mais 
positivo").

No entanto, no R não sei qual o comando que deve ser utilizado para identificar a direção, como se deve fazer no SPSS. Testei a curva no R também com 0 = com SM e 1 = sem SM, e deu a mesma coisa.

Alguém poderia me informar qual comando devo usar no R para que a curva fique igual ao SPSS?, ou seja, para que a curva AUC no R fique invertida!!

Comment: Kaluce, bem vindo ao Soft. Faltou você destacar seu código. Para saber sobre estes e outros detalhes acesse a Ajuda e faça o Tour.

Comment: Kaluce, por favor disponibilize uma parte dos dados para que possamos reproduzir o código, e se possível imagens do gráfico como você gostaria que ficasse.

Comment: @Leo Acho que você quis dizer *bem vindo ao sopt* correto? SOPT é uma abreviação do nome do site.

Comment: Kkkkkkk. Ok, me empolguei.... Vou ficar atento daqui para frente...

Comment: Olha, eu não consigo testar os códigos agora, mas esse valor de AUC que você conseguiu no R não é valido, o cálculo do AUC deve "inverter" caso ele seja menos que 0.5, ou seja, caso você calcule um AUC de 0.2, o correto seria 0.8.

Comment: Obrigada pelos comentários. Segue o link do dropbox com os dados em excel e também a imagem de como a curva foi obtida no SPSS e no R. Vejam que é a mesma curva, mas no R ela está invertida. Gostaria de saber qual o comando devo usar no R para obter a curva igual do SPSS. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wckj626n50q7n0h/AAAzHSVnUbMlSBmkby2zetSaa?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Com os dados do dropbox e o código original o gráfico fica normal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
> unlist(perf.auc@y.values)
[1] 0.7518116
```

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta. Testei novamente e deu certo. Achei estranho porque realmente não tinha dado certo antes. Deve ter sido alguma coisa estranha do sistema, sei lá...

Comment: Pessoal, estou com o mesmo problema para montar a curva ROC no R novamente. A curva ROC no R está ficando abaixo da linha diagonal com valor de AUC = 0,2481. Não fiz nenhuma mudança no código utilizado. O banco de dados continua no link do dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wckj626n50q7n0h/AAAzHSVnUbMlSBmkby2zetSaa?dl=0). Estou usando a versão 3.3.1 do R, versão 2.2-5 do Rcmdr e versão 10 do Windows de 2015. Alguém pode me ajudar a entender o que está acontecendo?